# Image transition while hovering another element

Tags: html, css

I have a school project to carry out and I'm out of ideas on how to fade a image in CSS while hovering on another element (anchor element) within same page.

The current method I am using is with :target and not(:target) selector. Basically one image will fade when is being targeted.

```
.home > img 
{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease
}

.home > img:target  {opacity: 1;}
.home > img:not(:target) {opacity: 0;}
```

But I'm sure there is a way to do this with hovering.

Comment: The delay between opacity:0 and opacity:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the anchor and the image are next to each other in the HTML, you could do something like:

```
.home a + .home img{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease
}
.home a:hover + .home img{
    opacity:1;
}
```

But the HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="home">
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <img src="whatever.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: i will try it now, but there are 2 images, and one must have opacity 0 while the other has 1 , just a matter of :not selector

Comment: Do you mean that you need this effect to happen just in one of the images? Then use a class. If multiple images have to work in opposite ways, use two classes and switch the opacity in one of them.

Comment: 2 link, 2 images. If that specific link is clicked then that specific image will fade in and the other out, and vice-versa for the other link. i understand now, tanks

Comment: I think this is the best you could get without JS. You'd have to use labels and not links though. http://jsbin.com/aSeKuzu/1/edit